# One horizontal line monitor LED

Tags: windows-10, display

My monitor has a horizontal line with color that interacts with what's behind it after a storm.

**info: LED monitor, VGA tested and tested power source**

OBS: my monitor flashed like it was unplugged and plugged in during a **thunderstorm** 3 times.

Images:
[image: Locked windows]
[image: Another color]
[image: Interacting with mouse]

is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I guess that line is broken. What is the question?

Comment: You have a dead row of pixels, replace the monitor

Comment: it is not possible to solve inside?

Comment: @joth Possible and practical often dont go hand in hand.  While is *may* be possible, the amount of time, effort, and money spent is not worth the *very, very small* chance it can be repaired.  Purchasing a new monitor is the best choice.